# How to validate a combo box in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am creating a mobile app using ionic framework.
I have a form which I have created for my hybrid mobile application..

I need to check whether the user has filled all the fields in the form..

my code...

```
<ion-view view-title="Request">
  <ion-content>

  <form novalidate>
      <div class="list">

        <label class="item item-input item-select">
          <div class="input-label">
            Request Type:
          </div>
          <select>
            <option selected>--Please select--</option>
            <option>Car Pass Ticket</option>
            <option>Seminar Pass</option>
            <option>Identy Card</option>
          </select>
        </label>

           <label class="item item-input">
            <textarea placeholder="Description" name="description" ng-minlength="20" required ></textarea>
          </label>
          <br/>
        <!--   <div class="padding">
          <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="submit(description)">
            Submit
          </button>
          </div> -->
            <div class="padding">
            <button class="button button-positive" ng-disabled="request.$invalid" ng-click="submit(description)">
            Submit
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Can some one kindly help me to validate the combo-box..

any kind of help is highly appreciated......

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
<form name="register_form"  ng-submit="submitDetails(user)" novalidate=""> 
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="position:relative;">
            <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
            <input type="text" name="user_first_name" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="user.firstName" ng-required="true">
            <p ng-show="register_form.user_first_name.$invalid && !register_form.user_first_name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </label>
        <!--omitted-->
        <input type="submit" class="button button-royal"  value="register">
    </div>
</form>
```

Form name is register_form,

```
<form name="register_form"  ng-submit="submitDetails(user)" novalidate="">
```

Input name is user_first_name,

```
<input type="text" name="user_first_name" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="user.firstName" ng-required="true">
```

So validation must pass through those fields

```
 <p ng-show="register_form.user_first_name.$invalid && !register_form.user_first_name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
```

Model itself doesn't have $invalid or $pristine properties, so it doesn't make sense

For phone field

```
<input type="number" name="user_phone" placeholder="Phone No" ng-model="user.phone" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="true">
<span class="help-block" ng-show="register_form.user_phone.$error.required || register_form.user_phone.$error.number">Valid phone number is required</span>
<span class="help-block" ng-show="((register_form.user_phone.$error.minlength || register_form.user_phone.$error.maxlength) && register_form.user_phone.$dirty) ">phone number should be 10 digits</span>
```

Comment: thanx for your response... I have a combo box to select the type of request..... how do I validate that ???

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Give name attribute to your form

```
 <form name="myForm" novalidate>
```

2) declare the request types inside of your scope like this:

```
$scope.requestType = [
    { code: "carPass", name: "Car Pass Ticket" },
    { code: "seminarPass", name: "Seminar Pass" },
    { code: "identityCard", name: "Identy Card"}
];
```

3) declare select box like this:

```
<select name="requestType" ng-model="request" required
    ng-options="request.code as request.name for request in requestType" >
    <option value="">--Please select--</option>
</select>
```

4)  Inside submit method check for $valid attribute of form.

```
$scope.submit1 = function(description){
   if($scope.myForm.$valid){
      // Do your stuff
   }else{
      // Do your stuff
   } 
}
```

Comment: thanx u :) I will see

Comment: Do u meant the $scope in the controller??? and code wht i have given is my html code...

Comment: Yes, use controller scope.